# `path` permalink property for collections in Jekyll

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to customize the permalinks for the pages in my collection. The directory looks like this:

```
writing
 |
 --file.md
 --file2.md
 --some-dir/
    |
    --another.md
    --something.md
```

I want the URLs to be

- /writing/[file-title]/index.html
- /writing/[file2-title]/index.html
- /writing/some-dir/[another-title]/index.html
- /writing/some-dir/[something-title]/index.html

I tried setting my collections `permalink` to

```
permalink: /:collection/:path/:title
```

but `:path` contains the full path (including the filename), instead of just the path to the file's directory.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

The nearest thing you can get will be with `permalink: /:collection/:path/`. Your file name just has to be the slugified title. `title: My title -> my-title.md`